# Can't convert list string to integer

Tags: python, python-3.x

I cant convert a list with a string to an integer.

```
num = ['123']
```

When I try:

```
print(int(num))
```

I get error:

```
TypeError: int() argument must be a string, a bytes-like object or a number, 
not 'list'
```

when I try:

```
print(int(str(num)))
```

I get error:

```
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: "['123']"
```

Comment: You can't convert a list to an integer, but you can convert the string value in the list to an integer.

Comment: By using `int(num[0])`

Comment: note that you can also fail to convert `num = set(['123'])` :) trial and error isn't the best way to solve issues.

Answer (score 1):

To convert all items of a list of strings:

```
int_list = [int(x) for x in num]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can just do:

```
print(int(num[0]))
```

given that a list only has one member.

Answer (score 0):

Typing into Python Shell:

```
>>> num=['123']
>>> type(num)
<class 'list'>
>>> type(num[0])
<class 'str'>
```

So as You can simply assume you cannot convert instance of a Class 'list' into an int as well as str.